# Are there any tools that can inline css?

Tags: css, email, xhtml

Because some email clients don't properly render external stylesheets (or even styles within the `<head>` of an HTML email message), inlining CSS is a common approach to try to maintain consistent look and feel between a website and emails. But manually inlining styles is painful and error prone.

I'm looking for a way to let users create messages using the same stylesheet as their website uses, but then converting the text into a more email appropriate format prior to sending. While it's certainly possible to write a tool that reads styles and the DOM, injecting the correct inline style for each element, I'm hoping there's already a tool available that does this. Unfortunately, my googling hasn't yielded any useful results.

Do you know of any tools that can inline CSS styles? I'm not picky about the language, though if it's not open source, I'll probably just write my own.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you looking for a tool that uses the DOM to inject inline styles previously defined (won't work in an e-mail, scripts are disabled) or something that will allow you to define some styles and have it automatically add a n appropriate style attribute to each matching element?

Comment: @Andrew: I think he meant the latter.

Comment: I think the latter as well, but I also believe he wants to be able to do it before it is sent, as in: write the HTML and CSS, inline it, and then send the document.

Comment: DeadHead is right - the user would create a message using the same stylesheet the site uses. I would parse the message to inline the css prior to sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premailer at http://code.dunae.ca/premailer.web/ is a good tool if your layout is straightforward and your HTML is tidy. It behaves poorly on badly-formatted HTML though, I don't know if it's something you'd refer a client to.

Source is available at http://code.google.com/p/premailer/. MIT License.

Comment: There's a new version here http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Answer (score 3):

There is also [premailer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer/) as a Python package.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby/Rails, there's https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer. That gem is wrapped by https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3 if you need Rails 3 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp also provides an [Automatic CSS Inliner Tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) on their website. Seems to work pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

MailerMailer provides their [Magic CSS Inliner](http://www.mailermailer.com/labs/tools/magic-css-inliner-tool.rwp) on their website. Additionally the underlying library which runs that page is available for Perl via [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/CSS-Inliner/lib/CSS/Inliner.pm) and [GitHub](https://github.com/kamelkev/CSS-Inliner).